# Cocos2d with browserify: cc.Layer is undefined

Tags: javascript, browserify, babeljs, cocos2d-js

I'm trying to get started with Cocos2d using Javascript, but I wanted to compile from ES6 and manage my dependencies using Browserify. So I'm outputting my compiled javascript to my Cocos2d project directory as main.js.

When I try to run the project, I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'extend' of undefined
```

at this line:

```
var HelloWorldLayer = cc.Layer.extend({
```

This wasn't happening when I ran the software without ES6/browserify, but I'm not sure why the `cc` variable would be any different (it is defined, but without the Layer property). I have also tried placing this above that line: `const cc = window.cc`, but this doesn't fix the issue either.

If anyone could explain what is going on here or how to fix it, I would greatly appreciate it.

I can post more of the code (it's almost identical to the base hello world app) or my gulpfile tasks if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran into the same problem. It seems that classes like `cc.Layer` are only available after calling `cc.game.run()`.

So you would have to ensure that `cc.game.run()` is called before the rest of your code is executed.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve the issue by leaving CocosJS's main.js out of the Browserify build and using it to pass the correct `cc` into the compiled app by exposing a function `window.startApp`:

main.js (uncompiled)

```
cc.game.onStart = function(){
    if(!cc.sys.isNative && document.getElementById("cocosLoading")) //If referenced loading.js, please remove it
        document.body.removeChild(document.getElementById("cocosLoading"));

    window.startApp(cc);
};
cc.game.run();
```

app.js (compiled with Browserify/Babelify)

```
import "babel-core/polyfill";
import {values} from "lodash";
import HelloWorldScene from "hello-world-scene";
import res from "resources";

window.startApp = (cc) => {
        // Pass true to enable retina display, disabled by default to improve performance
    cc.view.enableRetina(false);
    // Adjust viewport meta
    cc.view.adjustViewPort(true);
    // Setup the resolution policy and design resolution size
    cc.view.setDesignResolutionSize(800, 450, cc.ResolutionPolicy.SHOW_ALL);
    // The game will be resized when browser size change
    cc.view.resizeWithBrowserSize(true);
    //load resources
    cc.LoaderScene.preload(values(res), () => {
        cc.director.runScene(new HelloWorldScene());
    });
};
```

I'm still unsure why compiling main.js causes `cc` to lack essential properties. I think it might have to do with Browserify wrapping the compiled code in a strict mode function, but I wasn't able to disable strict mode to find out.

I created a github repo with my solution if anyone is interested:

https://github.com/FullR/cocos-es6-browserify